# How do I correctly capture a SAMLRequest in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, saml

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to setup a load-test for a SAML authenticated application.

**What I have done so far:**

I have captured my http traffic in JMeter and setup a scenario.

I have read up on how SAML works and tried to place what I am doing wrong.
But as far as I can see my expectation is viable.

**What I run into:**

I am having some trouble with the correlation of the SAMLRequest/SAMLResponse values.

**My Expected results vs actual results:**

I am looking to extract the value of the SAMLRequest and RelayState parameters from the responses I get when I login on my SP (application using SAML)

1. I login with username + password and then expect the responses I get in my Chrome Dev Tools to contain a SAMLRequest and RelayState
2. Then I wish to extract the value of SAMLRequest and use it in the next POST to obtain a SAMLResponse, which in turn I wish to extract in order to authenticate myself for the remainder of the scenario.
3. But I am misunderstanding something or I am overlooking a value somewhere, because I cannot seem to find where to capture SAMLRequest from to be able to reuse it in the first SAML post to get the SAMLResponse.

I only see SAMLRequest and RelayState in the POST of the recorded step, but in order to re-use this scenario I need to correlate these values but have no idea where to get them from as they do not seem to appear in the responses prior to this POST (at least not that I can see)

*Where do I extract the value of SAMLRequest from and how?*

Comment: You should actually get `SAMLRequest` value before making POST call for login. What I suggest is instead of traffic captured in chrome dev tools. Apart from that for chrome, there are some plugin which you can try out. here is the link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/SAML?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Amol pointed out above, I have found the issue is with the response logging or lack thereof in the Chrome Browser.

I have switched to FireFox and was able to view the expected responses I was looking for.
Whereas in Chrome these Responses were empty according to the Dev Tools.

The issue was fixed by correlating the values as you would normally expect within JMeter, which was made possible now I knew where to look for them.

Thank you Amol!